# Index out of bounds in for statement

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting an error during runtime: "index array out of bounds", i cannot find where though. The program is suppose to take 25 random numbers, separate them into even and odd numbers and display the separate groups. I debugged the first for-statement thats fine, its my second one but i do not know why. Can i not have two array elements equal each other?

```
public class EvensandOdds {



 public static void main(String[] args)  {

    int i;
    int countEven = 0;
    int countOdd = 0;
    int num;
    int numEven = 0;
    int numOdd = 0;
    int [] evenNum;
    int [] oddNum;
    int [] ranNum = new int[25];


    for (i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
        num = (int) (100 * Math.random());
        ranNum[i] = num;
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            numEven += 1;
        } else numOdd += 1;
    }

    evenNum = new int[numEven];
    oddNum = new int [numOdd];

    for (i = 0; i <= 24; i++) {
        if (ranNum[i] % 2 == 0) {
            evenNum[countEven] = ranNum[i]; //This separates the two groups into different arrays. Is this a valid statement?
            countEven += 1;
        } else oddNum[countOdd] = ranNum[i];
        countOdd += 1;
    }

    System.out.print("Your even numbers are: \n");
    for (i = 0; i <= countEven; i++) {
        System.out.print(evenNum[i]);
    }

    System.out.print("Your odd numbers are: \n");
    for (i = 0; i <= countOdd; i++) {
        System.out.print(oddNum[i]);
    }



 }
}
```

Comment: Look at your stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `countOdd += 1` is executed for both even and odd numbers, try changing these lines:

   ```
   } else oddNum[countOdd] = ranNum[i];
    countOdd += 1;
   ```

   into:

   ```
   } else { 
       oddNum[countOdd] = ranNum[i];
       countOdd += 1; 
   }
   ```
2. Change (as Lion suggested)

   ```
   for (i = 0; i <= countEven; i++) {
   ```

   and

   ```
   for (i = 0; i <= countOdd; i++) {
   ```

   into

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < countEven; i++) {
   ```

   and

   ```
   for (i = 0; i < countOdd; i++) {
   ```

Comment: Same thing. The last statement in a for loop - "else", doesnt need brackets.

Comment: @KamikazeStyle Huh... There is no special rule for `else`. If there is no bracket, only the next statement is in the `else` block.

Comment: @KamikazeStyle Just try this suggestion before downvoting, please. You need to put these two statements inside braces as they should be called together when a random number is odd.

Comment: @KamikazeStyle : In addition to this answer, you need to change `for (i = 0; i <= countEven; i++)` to `for (i = 0; i < countEven; i++)` and `for (i = 0; i <= countOdd; i++)` to `for (i = 0; i < countOdd; i++)`. Change `<=` to `<`, in short.

Comment: @AdamSiemion : KamikazeStyle, the OP cannot downvote. Downvoting requires at least 125 reputation that he doesn't have until now.

Comment: im not down voting anybody, i dont agree if someones trying to help me (or anyone) and you don't answer correctly to deduct their reputation (im not helping you next time lol) but yea that helped it the numbers in the for -statement that were wrong thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

The `countOdd += 1;` statement is not inside a pair of braces hence it gets executed even when the number is even.

```
} else { 
    oddNum[countOdd] = ranNum[i];
    countOdd += 1; 
}
```

This should solve your error.

Answer (score 0):

oddNum array length is 8... but you use a larger countOdd and this causes the exception specifically on line:

```
oddNum[countOdd] = ranNum[i];
```

This problem is caused because   countOdd += 1; is not contained within brackets like:

```
else addNum[countOdd++] = ranNum[i];
```